# Is there a way for resolve this import?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm trying to import languages in local with `("@angular/common/locales")`, i do a foreach where the value is the lang and i concatenate it in the import.

The problem is that the build gives me this error:
`"./locales is not exported in package.json".` (i have alredy tryied to run npm install)

If i use "\" (so the import is "@angular\common\locales") the import works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes but no.

You can't have a dynamic import without relying on magic comments to hint the bundler which file the embedded in your build artifact.

But as pointed out by one of the [angular cli maintainers](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22154#issuecomment-967061797):

> It's important to point out that using Webpack specific features such as magic comments are not supported by the Angular tooling team. The fact that the Angular CLI is using Webpack is an implementation detail which can change in the future.

Currently the Angular is header toward deprecated the usage of webpack as a builder and rely on vite/esbuild.

So you probably should better have a static import.